# Getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in C# for MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

i want to create a material database with c# and MS Access SQL:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string provStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
        string openStr = "Data source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MaterialDB.mdb";

        // Create structure, if not exist
        con = new OleDbConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = provStr + openStr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        OleDbCommand cmdTest = con.CreateCommand();

        cmdTest.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE NomCom (" + Environment.NewLine +
                          "          ID INT         NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY," + Environment.NewLine +
                          "      ValueTest VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL   UNIQUE" + Environment.NewLine +
                          ");" + Environment.NewLine;
        cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmdTest.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NomCom (ValueTest)" + Environment.NewLine +       //ID    ValueTest
                              "SELECT @valuenomcom;";
        cmdTest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuenomcom", "Steel");
        cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This is working fine.

But when i try to insert only if the item does not exist with

```
private void ...
    {
        cmdTest.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NomCom (ValueTest)" + Environment.NewLine +       //ID    ValueTest
                              "SELECT @valuenomcom WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NomCom WHERE Value = @valuenomcom);" + Environment.NewLine;
        cmdTest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuenomcom", "Steel");
        cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This does not working.
I am getting this error:

Getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@valuenomcom WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NomCom WHERE Value = @valuenomcom)'.

But i have no idea what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you run `INSERT INTO NomCom (ValueTest) SELECT 'Steel' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NomCom WHERE Value = 'Steel');` inside Access itself, what happens?

Comment: Why is opening the connection the only line in your try block? Shouldn't that include ALL the logic so you can handle errors? And having logic in a button click to create a table seems like a bad idea. It means you can't click the button more than once.

Comment: its only a test button, I did not pay attention to all programming conventions
@mjwills same error: Getting a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''Steel' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NomCom WHERE Value = 'Steel')'.

Comment: So what is the value of your CommandText when it crashes?

Comment: @SeanLange the value is
INSERT INTO NomCom (ValueTest)
SELECT 'Steel' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NomCom WHERE Value = 'Steel');

Comment: That is valid in sql server, but see what happens in Access.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza here is some sample code with that syntax. create table #NomCom(ValueTest varchar(20));insert #NomCom(ValueTest)select 'Steel' where not exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'Steel');select * from #NomCom;drop table #NomCom

Comment: @SeanLange You are right http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e4e7/1, so most like it access doesn't support that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access so cant test syntax. But following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16530237/3470178

You can do something like this:

```
cmdTest.CommandText = 
     "INSERT INTO NomCom (ValueTest)" + Environment.NewLine +       //ID    ValueTest
     "SELECT * 
      FROM ( SELECT @valuenomcom as newValue ) as Q
      WHERE Q.newValue NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM NomCom WHERE Value = @valuenomcom);" +
      Environment.NewLine;
cmdTest.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuenomcom", "Steel");
cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course test it first on Access.

Comment: then I get this: Query input must contain at least one table or query. (Error 3067)